Explicit path-homotopy in proof that every connected and locally simply connected topological space has a universal cover (as in Lee).
This question pertains to the proof of the following statement in Lee ("Introduction to Topological Manifolds"; loosely paraphrased):

Let $X$ be a connected and locally simply connected space. Then $X$ has a universal covering space.

On page 300, in step 2 of the proof, we are given some path $f:I \to X$ such that $f(0) = x_0$. Furthermore, we define, for each $t \in [0,1]$, the following map:
$$f_{t}(s) = f(ts).$$
We also define $f_{t_0t}(s) = f(t_0+s(t-t_0))$. Then Lee claims that $f_t$ is path-homotopic to $f_{t_0} \ast f_{t_0t}$. How would one go about constructing this path-homotopy explicitly?

What have you tried?

Remember two facts: If $h\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous functions and $f$ and $g$ are paths in $X$ for which $f\ast g$ is defined, then:
$$
h\circ(f\ast g) = (h\circ f)\ast (h\circ g)
$$
Furthermore, if $K$ is a path-homotopy between $f$ and $g$, then $h\circ K$ is a path-homotopy between $h\circ f$ and $h\circ g$.
Let $t_0, t\in [0,1]$ and $p,q,r\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$ be the paths given by
\begin{align*}
p(s) &= ts\\ 
q(s) &= t_0s\\
r(s) &= t_0 + s(t - t_0)
\end{align*}
Notice that $p(0) = 0 = q(0)$,
$
q(1) = t_0 = r(0)
$ and $r(1) = t = p(1)$
so $q\ast r$ is well-defined and has the same initial and final point of $p$. Also notice
that $f_t(s) = f\circ p(s), f_{t_0}(s) = f\circ q(s), f_{t_0t}(s) = f\circ r(s)$, so
$$
f_{t_0}\ast f_{t_0t} = f\circ (q\ast r).
$$
Therefore, you just need to prove that $p$ is path-homotopic to $q\ast r$ and then compose that path-homotopy with $f$ to find the desired path-homotopy. Because $[0,1]$ is convex and $p$ and $q\ast r$ have the same initial and final points, the map $H\colon [0,1]\times [0,1]\to [0,1]$ given by $H(s,\lambda) = (1 - \lambda)p(s) + \lambda(q\ast r)(s)$ is a path-homotopy. Hence, $f\circ H$ is the desired path-homotopy.
To get the explicit form of this homotopy, you just need to open it.
